# How to configure two database in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to configure two database on same project by configuring two CFG file,

I tried but it is always use the first configuration file,

May i know how can i use two database on same project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, what you need to do is to open two different session factory for different databases. 
For example:

```
Configuration configA=new Configuration();//use the default hibernate.cgf.xml file
Congiruration configB=new Configuration.configure('/hibernate_db2.cfg.xml') // use hibernate_db2.cfg.xml under root folder.
SessionFactory sfa=configA.buildSessionFactory();
SessionFactory sfb=configB.buildSessionFactory();
```

Now, you open different session using different db.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but after this how can i get session using sfa and sfb ?? like 
  sf.openSession();

Comment: @Himanshu Sharma Yes, you need to handle session manually, that means open session and close session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two configuration files.

```
hibernate-mysql.cfg.xml

hibernate-oracle.cfg.xml
```

And code should be like this.

**mysql configuration**

```
private static SessionFactory sessionAnnotationFactory; 

sessionAnnotationFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate-mysql.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionAnnotationFactory.openSession();
```

**oracle sql configuration**

```
sessionAnnotationFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate-oracle.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionAnnotationFactory.openSession()
```